# "mapping values are not allowed in this context" Alertmanager.yml

Tags: linux, proxy, smtp, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm using Alertmanager 0.20 with Prometheus. The configuration at alertmanager.yml is ok, but if I try to add the proxy_url once I'm behind a proxy, and according with the documentation [configuration](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/), we need to set proxy_url under http_config.

Using those two, Alertmanager starts to fail with the following error:

```
systemd[1]: Stopped Alert Manager.
systemd[1]: Started Alert Manager.
alertmanager[22866]: level=info ts=2020-12-30T17:37:20.679Z caller=main.go:216 msg="Starting Alertmanager" version="(version=0.21.0, branch=HEAD, revision=4c6c03ebfe21009c546e4d1e9b92c371d67c021d)"
alertmanager[22866]: level=info ts=2020-12-30T17:37:20.679Z caller=main.go:217 build_context="(go=go1.14.4, user=root@dee35927357f, date=20200617-08:54:02)"
alertmanager[22866]: level=info ts=2020-12-30T17:37:20.680Z caller=cluster.go:161 component=cluster msg="setting advertise address explicitly" addr=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port=9094
alertmanager[22866]: level=info ts=2020-12-30T17:37:20.681Z caller=cluster.go:623 component=cluster msg="Waiting for gossip to settle..." interval=2s
alertmanager[22866]: level=info ts=2020-12-30T17:37:20.705Z caller=coordinator.go:119 component=configuration msg="Loading configuration file" file=/etc/prometheus/alertmanager.yml
alertmanager[22866]: level=error ts=2020-12-30T17:37:20.705Z caller=coordinator.go:124 component=configuration msg="Loading configuration file failed" file=/etc/prometheus/alertmanager.yml err="yaml: **line 4: mapping values are not allowed in this context**"
alertmanager[22866]: level=info ts=2020-12-30T17:37:20.705Z caller=cluster.go:632 component=cluster msg="gossip not settled but continuing anyway" polls=0 elapsed=23.966326ms
systemd[1]: alertmanager.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: alertmanager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
prometheus[14952]: level=error ts=2020-12-30T17:37:20.779Z caller=notifier.go:527 component=notifier alertmanager=http://localhost:9093/api/v1/alerts count=2 msg="Error sending alert" err="Post \"http://localhost:9093/api/v1/alerts\": dial tcp [::1]:9093: connect: connection refused"
systemd[1]: alertmanager.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: alertmanager.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
systemd[1]: Stopped Alert Manager.
systemd[1]: alertmanager.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
systemd[1]: alertmanager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start Alert Manager.
```

My alertmanager version:

```
alertmanager, version 0.21.0 (branch: HEAD, revision:
4c6c03ebfe21009c546e4d1e9b92c371d67c021d)   build user:      
root@dee35927357f   build date:       20200617-08:54:02   go version: 
go1.14.4
```

My alertmanager.yml

```
global:
http_config:
proxy_url: http://ip:port
 smtp_smarthost: smtp_server_name:port
 smtp_from: from@email.com
 smtp_auth_username: auth@email.com
route:
  group_by: [alertname]
  repeat_interval: 1m
  receiver: live-monitoring

receivers:
- name: live-monitoring
  email_configs:
  - to: to@email.com
```

Any idea how to make alertmanager working and sending emails with the proxy configuration? And I can't set http_config and proxy_url before route: or receivers, otherwise

```
field http_config not found in type config.plain
```

Answer (score 0):

Indentation matters in YAML. You seem to have it broken in multiple places in your config. Quick *sample* of proper structure:

```
global:
  http_config:
    proxy_url: ....
  smtp_smarthost:
  ...
route:
  ...
receivers:
  ...
```

Note the spaces at the beginning and how they signify nesting of configuration options.